# How to choose indices of subintervals in binary search?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

iterative binary search algorithm. I am wrote algorithm in 2 different ways. the change i made was high = len(data) and high = len(data) -1 . In both cases algorithm runs fine. But in most of the sites they show high = len(data) -1 is correct way. so is using -1 is better and why?

1st code)

```
def iterative_binary_search(data, target):
    low = 0
    high = len(data)               # this line is where I need help
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[mid]:
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return False
```

2nd code)

```
def iterative_binary_search(data, target):
    low = 0
    high = len(data) -1           # this line is where I need help
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[mid]:
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the codes doesn't run fine.

Calling `ibs1` the first one, with `high=len(data)`, and `ibs2` the second one, with `high = len(data)-1`, I get :

```py
>>> haystack = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> ibs2(haystack, 11)
False
>>> ibs1(haystack, 11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in ibs1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### How to decide between `len(data)` and `len(data) - 1`

You need to decide what `low` and `high` stand for, and make it very clear in your mind. When `low=3` and `high=6`, what does it mean? Does it mean we are searching between list indices 3 and 6 included? Or excluded? That's up to you to decide. If it's included, then you should use `high = len(data) - 1`, because that is the index of the highest element of the array. If it's excluded, you should use `high = len(data)`, because that is one past the index of the highest element in the array.

Both decisions are fine. But then this decision must reflect in the logic of the remaining of the code.

Hence, this code would be correct as well:

```py
def ibs3(haystack, needle):
  low = 0
  high = len(haystack)
  while low < high:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if needle == haystack[mid]:
      return True
    elif needle < haystack[mid]:
      high = mid
    else:
      low = mid + 1
  return False
```

Note that in python, the convention is most often to include `low` and exclude `high`. For instance, `print(list(range(7, 10)))` prints `[7, 8, 9]`: no number 10 in there!

Comment: Thank you.I understand now why high = len(data) - 1 is better